# Возникает ошибка, помогите пожалуйста, очень прошу. Vk-io , node.js , javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, вконтакте, бот

Код: Можно найти тут -> https://github.com/ADM00103/vkbotGameBot/blob/master/Bot.js

Ошибка:

C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\MoneyBot\node_modules\vk-io\lib\index.js:9234
this.callbackService = options.callbackService
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'callbackService')
at new VK (C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\MoneyBot\node_modules\vk-io\lib\index.js:9234:40)
at Object. (C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\MoneyBot\bot.js:2:12)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

```
vk.setOptions({
    token: '',
});
```

заменить на:

```
const vk = new VK({
    token: '',
})
```

через .setOptions идёт ошибка